# Instagram API: Fetching user posts

Tags: app-store, instagram, instagram-api

I need to show posts from a certain Instagram account in my app. Since dev API(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram) requires users to log in, am I allowed to directly use graphql API like this [https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?doc_id=17991233890457762&variables={"id":"173560420","first":12}](https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?doc_id=17991233890457762&variables=%7B%22id%22:%22173560420%22,%22first%22:12%7D)
?